# I have this acoustic guitar pickup. What is a good software for it?

Tags: microphone, guitar

I have bought this cheap (10$) guitar pickup for an acoustic guitar, which I have connected it to my laptop's 3.5mm microphone port:

[image: Image of the pickup]

This is for a 14 years old kid.

What program can he use to remove the noise of the microphone (this microphone produces A LOT of noise) and add cool effects to the sound (like transform it in another instrument or an electric guitar - in real time). It should be easy to use, allow recording the sound and transforming it **and not too CPU-heavy**. The laptop is a Core 2 Duo 2.5 GHz, with a weak graphic card.

The price of the program is not important. It can be expensive.

Comment: What kind of noise are you getting from the mic?

Comment: Static maybe. It is constant, even when the guitar is not playing, and it is fairly loud. Maybe a filter could do the trick.

Comment: In this case, I would get cheap software (Arduino) and spend more money on the mic, rather than the other way around.

Comment: True, that's a better option, but I can't (due to time) buy another mic. Which software should I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a computer programmer, one of the first rules you learn is "Garbage In, Garbage Out". Once the correctness of the data - or in this case the quality of the sound - is gone, there's very little that can be done to bring it back into a usable state. Keep this in mind when deciding how best to spend your money which can easily disappear on a whole myriad of different items from instruments, mics, cables, pedals, outboards, rigs to DAW software.

For the moment I would prioritise your setup like this:

1. Pickup
2. Soundcard
3. Effects (dry or wet)
4. Noise removal

Firstly, get an acoustic pickup that has low (acceptable) noise. You can test this out by listening through a good set of headphones before putting it through a computer. If the signal you're getting at the very source isn't good enough don't try to fix it once you get it into a digital recorded state.

Second, if you're going to be recording music on a PC it will be worth considering getting a soundcard for that purpose. If you're using a laptop you could get an external soundcard e.g. [DMX 6Fire](http://www.terratec.net/en/products/DMX_6Fire_USB_2084.html). There's nothing worse than not being able to get a good recording because your soundcard isn't low latency or powerful enough to keep up.

The only time I ever put distortion effects on an acoustic guitar sound it didn't come out too well but in principle there shouldn't be a problem. You could either buy a purpose built guitar FX pedal e.g. [Digitech Grunge](http://www.digitech.com/products/Pedals/Grunge.php), [Boss Metal Zone](http://www.bosscorp.co.jp/products/en/MT-2/) or use software on the clean acoustic signal later e.g. the [Fruity Blood Overdrive](http://flstudio.image-line.com/help/html/plugins/Fruity%20Blood%20Overdrive.htm) plugin for FL Studio. I'd say the pedal route should be if the 14 yr-old will some day gig or otherwise want to tailor their rock distortion or whatever and let it be portable.

A good [DAW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_audio_workstation) system will come with noise removal software but (a) you're looking at spending a lot of money for just recording an acoustic guitar and (b) it can still have unwanted side-effects compared to the original. I found when I needed to use noise reduction because of a badly recorded source signal the result had a very muddy sound. That's why I'd recommend considering the noise removal element last and instead try to get a system working that doesn't need it. Regardless though, if you choose to use software effects to change the sound away from an acoustic guitar you'll need a DAW that can handle a plugin to do so. I mentioned FL Studio but there are others (including free ones) mentioned in the wikipedia link above.

Comment: I'm probably just going with the DAW system. If money isn't a problem (but the computer is) which should I choose?

But have in mind, that it must be simple to use and have a friendly interface.

Do you think FL Studio is a good option?

Comment: Unlike some others on this site I'm not a recording professional and don't have the broadest expertise with different DAW software. I'm a skilled FL Studio user now but I remember how hard I found it to begin with, also I don't think it's the tool I'd use for real time effects instruments. I mentioned it as a good example of having a nice plugin for post recording guitar effects. The easy-to-use question is a good one and probably worthy of its own thread. Apologies for being inconclusive, I get the feeling time is of the essence on this question.

Comment: It is. And your question helped me. I may go with Ableton. +1, although not being able to vote up :)

Comment: Don't worry about it, glad I could be of some help at least.